# Как включить поддержку русского языка в Vintage Mode (Vim) Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublime-text, vim

Как включить поддержку кириллицы? Немного надоело каждый раз переключать раскладку для command mode.

Comment: Мне кажется, что это 2 разных вопроса - про кириллицу и про кавычки - и их стоило бы оформить отдельно.

Comment: Разделил, с vimом разобрался вроде-бы

Comment: @B.Yakushev, если разобрались, изложите, пожалуйста, результаты в виде ответа на вопрос.

Comment: @alexander barakin увы, но ответа на мой вопрос я так и не нашел

Answer (score 2):

Решение, как назначить кириллическим буквам и символам русской раскладки те же команды, что и символам из английской, располагающимся с ними рядом на одной клавище, — `й` такую же, как и `q`, `ц` —  `w` и так далее.

Если было

```
{ "keys": ["q", "<character>"], "command": "vi_begin_record_macro",
    "context": [{"key": "setting.command_mode"}]
},
```

мы должны добавить в файл хоткеев:

```
{ "keys": ["й", "<character>"], "command": "vi_begin_record_macro",
    "context": [{"key": "setting.command_mode"}]
},
```

Чтобы не тратить время на самостоятельное редактирование для каждой клавиши, есть код, где всё сделали за нас. <kbd>Preferences</kbd> → <kbd>Key Bindings - User</kbd> → вставляем в открывшийся файл [**этот текст**](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cyberxndr/sublime-vintage-cyrillic/master/cyrillic.sublime-keymap) (на всякий случай [**архивная копия**](http://archive.ec/LG2a8)) → сохраняем.

Если у Вас в данном файле уже назначены какие-то пользовательские горячие клавиши, уберите лишние [квадратные скобки], пример:

*Было:*

```
[
{ "keys": ["alt+home"], "command": "sublimeserver_browser" },
{ "keys" : ["ctrl+shift+,"], "command" : "open_dir", "args" : {"dir" : "$file_path"} },
]
```

*Стало:*

```
[
{ "keys": ["alt+home"], "command": "sublimeserver_browser" },
{ "keys" : ["ctrl+shift+,"], "command" : "open_dir", "args" : {"dir" : "$file_path"} },
{ "keys": ["escape"], "command": "exit_insert_mode",
    "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.command_mode", "operand": false },
        { "key": "setting.is_widget", "operand": false }
    ]
},
<Тут остальной код без квадратных скобок в конце, так как у нас уже есть завершающая квадратная скобка>
]
```

[Пишут](https://github.com/cyberxndr/sublime-vintage-cyrillic#installation), что можно изменить и содержимое файла `Default.sublime-keymap` в папке `Vintage`, однако при обновлениях Sublime Text 3 может его перезаписать, и ваши изменения пропадут, почему рекомендую редактировать именно файл, открывающийся после <kbd>Preferences</kbd> → <kbd>Key Bindings - User</kbd>.

Демонстрация:

[image: Command Mode в русской раскладке]

Если вы изменили дефолтные клавиши для команд в английской раскладке, придётся делать аналогичные поправки и в кириллической.