# Не работает русская клавиатурная раскладка в сочетаниях горячих клавиш Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Установил плагин Markdown Editing, синтаксис Markdown GFM. Хочу обернуть текст в код или квадратные скобки. Когда нахожусь в английской клавиатурной раскладке, проблем не возникает:

[image: Английская раскладка]

Но когда раскладка русская, я уже не могу обернуть текст:

[image: Русская раскладка]

Это неудобно, раздражает. Причём такое сразу с несколькими плагинами: в английской раскладке горячие клавиши работают, а в русской нет.

Подскажите, что делать?

Comment: Несколько раз видел этот вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 1. Суть проблемы

Откроем консоль: <kbd>Ctrl+`</kbd> (машинописный обратный апостроф, символ расположен на той же клавише, где кириллическая «ё») → вводим в открывшееся поле *sublime.log_input(True)*. Нажмём сначала <kbd>Ctrl+k</kbd> в английской раскладке, затем <kbd>Ctrl+л</kbd> в русской. Посмотрим, что выведется в консоли:

```
key evt: control+k
key evt: control+k
```

Если с системой нет проблем, результат должен быть аналогичным. А теперь нажмём <kbd>k</kbd> в английской, потом <kbd>л</kbd> в русской.

```
chr evt: k (0x6b)
chr evt: л (0x43b)
```

Sublime Text воспринимает *k* и *л* как разные символы, если они нажимаются не вместе со служебными клавишами. Если используется двойное нажатие хоткеев, <kbd>Ctrl+k,k</kbd> и <kbd>Ctrl+л,л</kbd> Sublime Text также видит по-разному.

Т.е. когда в качестве шортката используется одинарный символ, чтобы результат в русской раскладке был таким же, как в английской, придётся раскладку переключать. Так что если будете сами задавать сочетание для команды, без использования служебных клавиш, продублируйте запись и для русской раскладки, пример:

```
// Предпросмотр вики-страницы в плагине Mediawiker
    { "keys": ["ctrl+7", "p"], "command": "mediawiker_preview" },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+7", "з"], "command": "mediawiker_preview" },
```

---

### 2. Попытки урегулирования проблемы с разработчиками

Заявка в issue tracker Sublime Text висит долгое время, её приоритет [**обозначен как «minor»**](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/392). Есть [**предложение**](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/392#issuecomment-131031043) использовать в качестве идентификатора клавиши [**keycode вместо keysym**](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xmodmap), но по состоянию на сентябрь 2016 оно не реализовано на практике.
Разработчик плагинов [**отказался**](https://github.com/aziz/BetterFindBuffer/pull/25#issuecomment-244106771) принимать мой pull request, добавляющий хоткеи для русской раскладки.

Значит, придётся настраивать Sublime Text для русской раскладки самостоятельно.

---

### 3. Решение

На примере плагина BetterFindBuffer.

Устанавливаем плагин [**PackageResourceViewer**](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer): <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> → `PackageResourseViewer:Open Resourse` (благодаря [**fuzzy поиску**](https://habrahabr.ru/post/147856/) достаточно набрать просто `prvor`) → *MarkdownEditing* → *Default.sublime-keymap* (иногда *Default(ваша операционная система).sublime-keymap*) → в открывшемся файле ищем шорткаты, состоящие из одного символа, которого в русской раскладке нет или же он расположен на другой клавише. Пример:

```
{
  "keys": ["o"],
  "command": "find_in_files_open_file",
  "context": [
    { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.find-in-files" }
  ]
},
```

Заменяем o на соответствующую ей в русской раскладке букву, это `щ`:

```
{
  "keys": ["щ"],
  "command": "find_in_files_open_file",
  "context": [
    { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.find-in-files" }
  ]
},
```

*Preferences* → *Key Bindings - User* → вставляем в открывшийся файл код с буквой `щ`. Проделываем данное действие со всеми шорткатами без служебных клавиш, где это необходимо.

После того, как произвели действия, проверьте, всё ли работает нормально. Пример: в *Preferences* → *Key Bindings - Default* есть такой код:

```
{ "keys": ["\""], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "\"$0\""}, "context":
        [
            { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
            { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
            { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^(?:\t| |\\)|]|\\}|>|$)", "match_all": true },
            { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "not_regex_contains", "operand": "[\"a-zA-Z0-9_]$", "match_all": true },
            { "key": "eol_selector", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": "string.quoted.double - punctuation.definition.string.end", "match_all": true }
        ]
},
```

(`\"` — символ "кавычки-ёлочки". Для использования кавычки как литерала в JSON-файлах требуется её экранировать.)

Вы вставили в свой кеймап:

```
{ "keys": ["э"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "\"$0\""}, "context":
        [
            { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
            { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
            { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^(?:\t| |\\)|]|\\}|>|$)", "match_all": true },
            { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "not_regex_contains", "operand": "[\"a-zA-Z0-9_]$", "match_all": true },
            { "key": "eol_selector", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": "string.quoted.double - punctuation.definition.string.end", "match_all": true }
        ]
},
```

Но теперь когда вы просто вводите букву `э`, вводятся двойные кавычки. Код с буквой `э` не нужен, удаляем его из нашего файла. Проверяем — буква `э` пишется теперь нормально. Если после ваших действий с назначением команд клавишам русской раскладки символы русской раскладки заработают неправильно, значит, скорее всего, вы вставили лишнее, подлежащее удалению.

---

### 4. Поддержка русской раскладки для дефолтных хоткеев без служебных клавиш

Можно добавлять строки ниже в файл, открывающийся после *Preferences* → *Key Bindings - User*, сразу после установки Sublime Text, чтобы не приходилось переключаться при оборачивании текста в различные виды кавычек и скобок, а также при использовании Vintage Mode. Проверял, ошибок возникнуть не должно.

#### Обёртка текста в скобки и кавычки

```
//
//
// Дефолтные сочетания в русской раскладке клавиатуры
//
//
// Выделение {фигурными скобками}
{ "keys": ["Х"], "command": "wrap_block", "args": {"begin": "{", "end": "}"}, "context":
        [
            { "key": "indented_block", "match_all": true },
            { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
            { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
            { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_match", "operand": "^$", "match_all": true },
        ]
    },
{ "keys": ["Х"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "{${0:$SELECTION}}"}, "context":
        [
            { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
            { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": false, "match_all": true }
        ]
},
{ "keys": ["Ъ"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^\\}", "match_all": true }
    ]
},
// Выделение "кавычками-ёлочками"
{ "keys": ["Э"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "\"${0:$SELECTION}\""}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": false, "match_all": true }
    ]
},
{ "keys": ["Э"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^\"", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": "punctuation.definition.string.begin", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "eol_selector", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": "string.quoted.double - punctuation.definition.string.end", "match_all": true },
    ]
},
// Выделение 'одинарными кавычками'
{ "keys": ["э"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "'${0:$SELECTION}'"}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": false, "match_all": true }
    ]
},
{ "keys": ["э"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^'", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": "punctuation.definition.string.begin", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "eol_selector", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": "string.quoted.single - punctuation.definition.string.end", "match_all": true },
    ]
},
// Выделение [квадратными скобками]
{ "keys": ["х"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "[$SELECTION]$0"}, "context":
            [
                { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
                { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": false, "match_all": true },
                { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.html.markdown", "match_all": true }
            ]
},
{ "keys": ["х"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "[${0:$SELECTION}]"}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": false, "match_all": true }
    ]
},
{ "keys": ["ъ"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^\\]", "match_all": true }
    ]
},
```

#### Vintage Mode

Вставляем [**отсюда**](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cyberxndr/sublime-vintage-cyrillic/master/cyrillic.sublime-keymap), (на всякий случай [**архивная копия**](http://archive.ec/LG2a8), также см. [**ответ**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/548152/199934).

---

### 5. Поддержка русской раскладки в некоторых плагинах

Чтобы не мучились настраивать русскую раскладку для этих плагинов самостоятельно, готовый код:

#### BetterFindBuffer

```
// BetterFindBuffer, русская раскладка
{
  "keys": ["щ"],
  "command": "find_in_files_open_file",
  "context": [
    { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.find-in-files" }
  ]
},
{
  "keys": ["ф"],
  "command": "find_in_files_open_all_files",
  "context": [
    { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.find-in-files" }
  ]
},
{
  "keys": ["т"],
  "command": "find_in_files_jump_file",
  "context": [
    { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.find-in-files" }
  ]
},
{
  "keys": ["з"],
  "command": "find_in_files_jump_file",
  "args": { "forward": false },
  "context": [
    { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.find-in-files" }
  ]
},
{
  "keys": ["о"],
  "command": "find_in_files_jump_match",
  "context": [
    { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.find-in-files" }
  ]
},
{
  "keys": ["л"],
  "command": "find_in_files_jump_match",
  "args": { "forward": false },
  "context": [
    { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.find-in-files" }
  ]
},
{
  "keys": ["а"],
  "command": "bfb_fold_and_move_to_next_file",
  "context": [
    {"key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.find-in-files" }
  ]
},
{
  "keys": [","],
  "command": "bfb_toggle_popup_help",
  "context": [
    {"key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.find-in-files" }
  ]
},
```

#### Markmon

```
// Markmon, русская раскладка
{ "keys": ["ctrl+k", "ь"], "command": "markmon_toggle", "args":
        {
            "enable": true
        }
},
```

#### MarkdownEditing

```
   // MarkdownEditing, русская раскладка
   { "keys": ["ё"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "`${0:$SELECTION}`"}, "context":
       [
           { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
           { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": false, "match_all": true },
           { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.html.markdown", "match_all": true }
       ]
   },
   { "keys": ["ё"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/MarkdownEditing/macros/Skip Closing Character.sublime-macro"}, "context":
        [
            { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
            { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^`", "match_all": true },
            { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.html.markdown", "match_all": true }
        ]
   },
   { "keys": ["Ё"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "~~${0:$SELECTION}~~"}, "context":
           [
               { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
               { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": false, "match_all": true },
               { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.html.markdown", "match_all": true },
               { "key": "selector", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": "markup.raw", "match_all": true }
           ]
    },
   { "keys": ["№"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "#${0: ${SELECTION/(^ | $)//g} }#"}, "context":
           [
               { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": false, "match_all": true },
               { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.html.markdown", "match_all": true },
               { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "not_regex_contains", "operand": "#{6}", "match_all": true },
               { "key": "setting.mde.match_header_hashes", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
               { "key": "selector", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": "markup.raw", "match_all": true }
           ]
   },
   { "keys": ["№"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "#${0: ${SELECTION/(^ | $)//g}}"}, "context":
       [
           { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": false, "match_all": true },
           { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.html.markdown", "match_all": true },
           { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "not_regex_contains", "operand": "#{6}", "match_all": true },
           { "key": "setting.mde.match_header_hashes", "operator": "equal", "operand": false },
           { "key": "selector", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": "markup.raw", "match_all": true }
       ]
   },
   { "keys": ["№"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/MarkdownEditing/macros/Padded Headline.sublime-macro"}, "context":
       [
           { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": false, "match_all": true },
           { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.html.markdown", "match_all": true },
           { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "#{6}", "match_all": true },
           { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "#+", "match_all": true },
           { "key": "setting.mde.match_header_hashes", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
           { "key": "selector", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": "markup.raw", "match_all": true }
       ]
   },
   { "keys": ["№"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/MarkdownEditing/macros/Padded Headline.sublime-macro"}, "context":
       [
           { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": false, "match_all": true },
           { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.html.markdown", "match_all": true },
           { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "#{6}", "match_all": true },
           { "key": "setting.mde.match_header_hashes", "operator": "equal", "operand": false },
           { "key": "selector", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": "markup.raw", "match_all": true }
       ]
   },
   { "keys": ["Ю"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/MarkdownEditing/macros/Convert to Blockquote.sublime-macro"}, "context":
           [
               { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": false, "match_all": true },
               { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.html.markdown", "match_all": true },
               { "key": "selector", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": "markup.raw", "match_all": true }
           ]
```

Comment: (Для нагугливания ...) У меня не работало комментирование: `Ctrl+/`; на русской раскладке в Linux Mint 18 "Sarah" MATE. Добавил в настройки `{ "keys": ["ctrl+."], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": false } },` и всё заработало.

Comment: @RomanGrinyov, если что, это [**другая проблема**](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/392), не [**та, чьё решение описывается в данном ответе**](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1341). Спасибо.

Comment: А вот вы не подскажете случаем почему некоторое время висит запуск при открытии файла? То есть, например, я открываю файл, он быстро открывается, но ещё некоторое время висит запуск: http://i.imgur.com/p7TpR1i.png.

Comment: @RomanGrinyov, к сожалению, не смог понять, каким образом Вы открываете файлы( . Можете шаги для воспроизведения привести? (И лучше задать отдельный вопрос: 1. На него могут ответить и другие участники, 2. Столкнувшиеся с проблемой смотрят в комментариях сообщения по теме, не оффтоп.) Спасибо.

Comment: Да, вы правы ... Старею :) http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/592377/201026