# Зависшее окно при запуске файла в Sublime Text

Tags: linux, sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Когда Sublime Text НЕ запущен, то запуск файла для редактирования происходит быстро и то окно, которое указано на скриншоте, появляется на мгновение.

Когда Sublime Text ЗАпущен и я открываю файл для редактирования, то окно, указанное на скриншоте, висит секунд 5-10 и курсор становится «[Progress](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_cursor&preval=progress)». При этом файл открывается и его можно редактировать, но окно висит.

> Это как бы не окно (при клике по нему ничего не происходит), просто подходящее слово не нашёл.

Это очень отвлекает и похоже на какие-то неполадки. Как от этого можно избавиться?

[image: Зависшее окно при запуске файла в Sublime Text]

---

- Sublime Text 3
- Linux Mint 18 "Sarah" - MATE