# Не работают сочетания клавиш Sublime Text 3 на русской раскладке

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3, linux-mint

Сегодня устанавливал различные плагины для ST3, потом принялся за работу и понял, что никакие сочетания клавиш не работают. Снос плагинов не помогает.

Посмотрел на [Не работает русская клавиатурная раскладка в сочетаниях горячих клавиш Sublime Text 3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/563061/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88-sublime-t)

Открыл консоль, ввёл `sublime.log_input(True)` и получил

```
key evt: control+k
key evt: control+л
```

Видимо, что-то не так с системой? Использую Linux Mint 17.1 Cinnamon. Сегодня также менял тему системы (Откатывал, не помогло). Компьютер перезагружал, редактор перезапускал.

Comment: Такая же проблема на MacOs Sierra

Comment: Такая же проблема была в атоме пару месяцев назад, а сейчас её исправили. Можете попробовать его как альтернативу https://atom.io. Или geany установите из репозитория, если вам нужна быстрая IDE. Она тоже довольно мощная. Я конечно понимаю, что это не решение проблемы, но боюсь, её могут решить только разработчики sublime.

Comment: Ну или если в sublime можно биндить по несколько сочетаний на одно действие, продублируйте все сочетания с русскими буквами. Костыль конечно, но куда деваться?..